# Cookies File Not Generated PHP and cURL Login from Remote Site

Tags: php, curl

I do not receive a successful login to $loginUrl (i.e. no cookie.txt file is generated in the same directory as the file) based on the code below and therefore am unable to load HTML data from $url (i.e. echoes did not load). When I view the curl_exec for loginUrl, it looks like it doesn't submit the username and password to the form, although I have $store = curl_exec($ch), as the form is displayed instead of a successful login.

```
function parseDOM($data)
{
  global $projectID, $sRedirect, $database;
  libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  if(!$dom->loadHTML($data))
  {
    echo "did not load";
  }
}

$ch = @curl_init();
if($ch)
{
  $username = 'username';
  $password = 'password';
  //$url = 'https://global-factiva-com.libproxy.lib.unc.edu/ha/default.aspx#./!?&_suid=14977301633480007720669669887936';
  //trying different URL
  $url = 'https://global.factiva.com.libproxy.lib.unc.edu/redir/default.aspx?P=sa&NS=16&AID=9UNI011500&f=g&an=j000000020010807dw8b00lc2&cat=a';
  //loginUrl is the same as the URL for the form post action
  $loginUrl = 'https://sso.unc.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO;jsessionid=A2C0B6480084BED37E1104E903B07AA9?execution=e1s1';

  //Set the URL to work with
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
  // ENABLE HTTP POST
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  //Set the post parameters
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'j_username='.$username.'&j_password='.$password);
  //Handle cookies for the login
  $cookie=dirname(__FILE__)."\\cookie.txt";
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
  //execute the request (the login)
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  $store = curl_exec($ch);

  //now access the URL that requires login
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  $content=curl_exec($ch);
  $headers = curl_getinfo($ch);

  curl_close($ch);
  parseDOM($content);

}
```

Comment: What's the URL of the form? I'd like to see it myself and check the form field names, hidden fields, etc

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would the URL of the loginURL be what you need?

Comment: If I go to loginURL then I see http://i.imgur.com/KN1Uqiq.png

I need to see the login page that contains the username and password fields.

Comment: You are right. If you go to [link](https://global.factiva.com.libproxy.lib.unc.edu/redir/default.aspx?P=sa&NS=16&AID=9UNI011500&f=g&an=j000000020010807dw8b00lc2&cat=a) for example, then can click on Onyen Sign In button and that will take you to the login page.

Comment: Note: sometimes I see the following error when I use a different [link](https://global-factiva-com.libproxy.lib.unc.edu/ha/default.aspx#./!?&_suid=14977301633480007720669669887936): Error
The page you have requested is not accessible by using bookmarks or other methods of directly accessing the page. Please use the product navigation to access this page.



Error: 210139
Server: FWEB1 - 27137

Comment: as i have said so many, many times before, WHENEVER YOU'RE DEBUGGING CURL REQUESTS, ENABLE `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`

Comment: 1 obvious error you're doing, you're not urlencoding username/password, so if the username OR password contains spaces, or `&` or `?` or ÆØÅ  or a bunch of other characters, it wont work, the server will recieve the wrong username/password. fix that, `'j_username='.urlencode($username).'&j_password='.urlencode($password)`

Comment: @JustinWilson that link you posted, links to 4 different logins. where do you want to login? `Onyen`, or `AHEC`, or `Hospital Staff`, or `Self-Paced Courses`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the approach I would use. First, use Google Chrome and open the network inspector. If you then manually log in then you'll be able to see all the request headers sent, the form fields, etc.

Armed with this information you can construct a curl request and specify all the custom headers. I have worked with systems before that reject requests without a legitimate referer or user-agent.

So, for example ..

```
<?php

$username = 'hello';
$password = 'letmein';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://sso.unc.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO?execution=e1s1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'j_username:='.$username.'&j_password:='.$password.'&_eventId_proceed:=');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

$headers = [
    'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6',
    'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
    'Connection:keep-alive',
    'Content-Length:57',
    'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host:sso.unc.edu',
    'Origin:https://sso.unc.edu',
    'Referer:https://sso.unc.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO?execution=e1s1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1',
    'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

echo $output;

?>
```

Once you run this then hopefully you are logged in and the cookie is set. You can then make a second request using a new `curl_init()` to the second URL and include the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` parameters.

Hopefully this gives you something to work from. Good luck.

Comment: you're not urlencoding username/password, so if the username OR password contains spaces or `&` or ÆØÅ or a bunch of other characters, it wont work, the server recieves the wrong username/password. second, don't send the Content-Length header manually, curl will do that for you, and unlike you, curl wont mess up and send the wrong number. third, don't set the Host-header manually, curl will do that for you too. fourth, don't set the User-Agent header manually, rather set CURLOPT_USERAGENT, this ensures that if curl follows a "Location"-http redirect, the useragent is kept on each request

Comment: fifth, don't set the `Content-Type` header manually if you're using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` encoding, curl will automatically detect which encoding you used, and set the appropriate header, and unlike you, won't have any typos in doing so,  and you, sir, are using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-encoding.

Comment: sixth, why do you fake a referer header? some websites can detect that you have a fake referer header, and block you. instead, just make a normal request to that page, set CURLOPT_AUTOREFER, and have a real referer header. its safer

Comment: Code still not working. Also, the code does not have the call to the URL that I am trying to access after the loginURL.

Comment: whereVerbose information: [link](http://www.dreamplaybook.com/dreamplaybook/pto/verbose.txt)

Single Sign-On

UNC-Chapel Hill Single Sign-On - Error

An error occurred: NoSuchFlowExecutionException

Answer (score 1):

you haven't told us where you want to login, but in a comment, you posted this link `https://auth.lib.unc.edu/ezproxy_auth.php?url=https://global.factiva.com/ha/default.aspx` , which itself links to 4 different login pages. however, the CURLOPT_VERBOSE log you posted in the comment at [Cookies File Not Generated PHP and cURL Login from Remote Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610671/cookies-file-not-generated-php-and-curl-login-from-remote-site#comment76456594_44665799) suggests you are trying to login to the site called `Onyen`. after doing some research, turns out they have a very odd login system, which starts at https://auth.lib.unc.edu/ezproxy_auth.php?url=https://global.factiva.com/ha/default.aspx - make a GET request to that url, this will create a cookie session that you'll need for all subsequent requests, and give you needed information in the HTML. parse out the HTML `<form`-element that contains the `<input`-element that contains `Onyen` in the `value`-property (the input form to look for, looks like `<input name="submit" value="Onyen Sign In" accesskey="o" type="submit">`), this form element gives you 3 input elements who's value you need to add to your next GET request, whos url you get from the form's `action` attribute. i suspect all the values are constant, except the 1 called `auth`, which is probably unique to each cookie session, or ip address, or something like that. the URL as generated from my browser (and later, by php) turned out to be `https://auth.lib.unc.edu/authentication.php?url=https://global.factiva.com/ha/default.aspx&auth=shibboleth&submit=Onyen+Sign+In` - now if you did everything correctly, generating the correct url and sending it with the cookies recieved in the previous request, it should respond with a `302 Found` http-redirect, which you must follow. following this redirect, you get another page with a html with a single `<form` tag, whose url you must extract, and `<input` elements who's name and value you must parse out, and add to your neext POST request, which goes to `https://sso.unc.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO` - now this POST gives a http 302 Found redirect, which you must also follow. now follwing that redirect, you finally get to `https://sso.unc.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO?execution=e2s1`, where there's a html with a single `<form` tag, with `<input` elements who's name and value you must parse out, and fill out the `j_username` and `j_password` inputs, and add to your next POST request, which goes to `https://sso.unc.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO?execution=e2s1` - now sending that POST request with a valid username/password and cookie session, will probably get you logged in. here's an implementation, using DOMDocument/DOMXpath for HTML parsing, and hhb_curl from https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php for http/cookies stuff (its a libcurl wrapper), just replace `username_here` with a real username, and `password_here` with a real password, on line 72 & 73.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
require_once ('hhb_.inc.php');
function getFormUrl(\hhb_curl $hc, \DOMNode $form): string {
    $url = $form->getAttribute ( "action" );
    if (empty ( $url )) {
        $url = '';
    }
    if (! parse_url ( $url, PHP_URL_HOST )) {
        $url = 'https://' . rtrim ( parse_url ( $hc->getinfo ( CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL ), PHP_URL_HOST ), '/' ) . '/' . ltrim ( $url, '/' );
    }
    if (false === strpos ( $url, '?' )) {
        $url .= '?';
    }
    return $url;
}
$hc = new hhb_curl ( 'https://auth.lib.unc.edu/ezproxy_auth.php?url=https://global.factiva.com/ha/default.aspx', true );
$hc->exec ();
// hhb_var_dump ( $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getStdOut () );
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $hc->getResponseBody () );
$form = (new DOMXPath ( $domd ))->query ( '//input[contains(@value,\'Onyen Sign In\')]/parent::form' )->item ( 0 );
$url = getFormUrl ( $hc, $form );
// probably looks like $url = 'https://auth.lib.unc.edu/authentication.php?';
$queryparms = array ();
foreach ( $form->getElementsByTagName ( "input" ) as $input ) {
    $url .= urlencode ( $input->getAttribute ( "name" ) ) . '=' . urlencode ( $input->getAttribute ( "value" ) ) . '&';
}
$url = substr ( $url, 0, - 1 );
// hhb_var_dump ( $url );
$hc->exec ( $url );
// hhb_var_dump ( $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getStdOut () );
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $hc->getResponseBody () );
$form = $domd->getElementsByTagName ( "form" )->item ( 0 );
$url = getFormUrl ( $hc, $form );
$posts = array ();
foreach ( $form->getElementsByTagName ( "input" ) as $input ) {
    $name = $input->getAttribute ( "name" );
    if (empty ( $name )) {
        continue;
    }
    $posts [$name] = $input->getAttribute ( "value" );
}
// hhb_var_dump ( $posts );
$hc->setopt_array ( array (
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( $posts ),
        CURLOPT_URL => $url 
) );
$hc->exec ();
// hhb_var_dump ( $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getStdOut () );
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $hc->getResponseBody () );
$form = $domd->getElementsByTagName ( "form" )->item ( 0 );
$url = getFormUrl ( $hc, $form );
$posts = array ();
foreach ( $form->getElementsByTagName ( "input" ) as $input ) {
    $name = $input->getAttribute ( "name" );
    if (empty ( $name )) {
        continue;
    }
    $posts [$name] = $input->getAttribute ( "value" );
}
foreach ( $form->getElementsByTagName ( "button" ) as $button ) {
    $name = $button->getAttribute ( "name" );
    if (empty ( $name )) {
        continue;
    }
    $posts [$name] = $button->getAttribute ( "value" );
}

assert ( isset ( $posts ['j_username'] ), 'failed to find the username input!' );
assert ( isset ( $posts ['j_password'] ), 'failed to find the password input!' );
$posts ['j_username'] = 'username_here';
$posts ['j_password'] = 'password_here';
hhb_var_dump ( $posts );
$hc->setopt_array ( array (
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( $posts ),
        CURLOPT_URL => $url 
) );
$hc->exec ();
hhb_var_dump ( $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getStdOut () );
```

edit: fixed a bug where a `<button>` element's name didnt get appended to the POST data.

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try

Comment: I'm getting a HTTP ERROR 500 when I update this code and place the hhb_.inc.php file in the same directory

Comment: @JustinWilson and what does the php error logs say?

Comment: @JustinWilson (if you don't know where the error logs are, common locations include `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. or `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, else, it might be defined by the error_log directive in php.ini - by default though, it just sends it to the web server (usually Apache or Nginx), and the web server sends it to its own error log)

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in test.php on line 4

Comment: @JustinWilson oh, this code is written in PHP7, you'll get that error if you try to run it in PHP5.. though, it would probably run fine in PHP5 if you removed input type declarations, and return type declarations, and replace `hhb_.inc.php` with `hhb_.inc.php5.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147534/discussion-between-hanshenrik-and-justin-wilson).